# django left outer join filter non-matching records

Tags: django

The goal is to find out if a Survey Response doesn't have current answers for all top level questions.

This could be done by getting all top level questions for the Response, and then filter out the questions which don't have current answers.

I can write this in SQL but is there a way I can implement this using django's QuerySet interface?

**Models**

```py
class Survey(Model):
  ...

class SurveySection(Model):
  survey = ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='survey_sections')

class SurveyQuestion(Model):
  survey_section = ForeignKey(SurveySection, related_name='survey_questions')
  parent = ForeignKey('self') #questions can be nested

class SurveyResponse(Model):
  survey = ForeignKey(Survey, related_name='survey_responses')

class SurveyAnswer(Model):
  survey_response = ForeignKey(SurveyResponse, related_name='survey_answers')
  survey_question = ForeignKey(SurveyQuestion, related_name='survey_answer')
  is_current = BooleanField()
```

**SQL**

This should find all the top-level questions for the Survey the Response is for, getting the current answers that match those questions and removing the questions that don't have answers.

```sql
select * from survey_surveyquestion question
join survey_surveysection section on section.id = question.survey_section_id
join survey_survey survey on survey.id = section.survey_id
join survey_surveyresponse response on response.survey_id = survey.id
left outer join survey_surveyanswer answer on answer.survey_question_id = question.id and answer.is_current = true
where response.id = 16
  and answer.id is null
  and question.parent is null
```

Comment: I am unclear, on how to identify if the survey answer is right or wrong?

Comment: @ruddra It's not necessary to identify whether the answer is right or wrong. We only care that the answer is 'current' (is_current=True) for the set of questions we are looking.

Comment: sorry @ruddra the code was missing the field `is_current` - I've just edited the question and added that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this approach:

First, get number of questions which has parent null:

```
top_question_count = SurveyQuestion.objects.filter(parent__is_null=True).count()
```

Then, use it in filter:

```
from django.db.models imprt Count

SurveyResponse.objects.filter(
    survey_answers__survey_question__parent__is_null=True,
    is_current=True
).annotate(
    top_level_questions=Count('survey_answers__survey_question')
).filter(
    top_level_questions=top_question_count
)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `top_question_count` should be filtering on parent (right now it counts all questions)? Also, SurveyResponse should filter is_current on SurveyAnswer instead? But I understand how this works and it does answer the question. On a side question, if it was possible to have multiple answers to a question is there a way to get the unique question id count for the survey answers?

Comment: @richflow opps. It should be if the parent is null. Updated my answer